# How to select elements within an iframe element in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, puppeteer, webautomation

Since ESPN does not provide an API, I am trying to use Puppeteer to scrape data about my fantasy football league. However, I am having a hard time trying to login using puppeteer due to the login form being nested with an iframe element.

I have gone to http://www.espn.com/login and selected the iframe. I can't seem to select any of the elements within the iframe except for the main section by doing

```
    frame.$('.main')
```

This is the code that seems to get the iframe with the login form.

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('http://www.espn.com/login')
    await page.waitForSelector("iframe");

    const elementHandle = await page.$('div#disneyid-wrapper iframe');
    const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
    await browser.close()
```

I want to be able to access the username field, password field, and the login button within the iframe element. Whenever I try to access these fields, I get a return of null.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can get the iframe using `contentFrame` as you are doing now, and then call `$`.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('http://www.espn.com/login')

const elementHandle = await page.waitForSelector('div#disneyid-wrapper iframe');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
await frame.waitForSelector('[ng-model="vm.username"]');
const username = await frame.$('[ng-model="vm.username"]');
await username.type('foo');
await browser.close()
```

[image]

Comment: frame.$('[ng-model="vm.username"]') seems to return null.

Comment: @SwapnikK you could also use a waitForSelector. Answer edited.

Answer (score 14):

I had an issue with finding stripe elements. 
The reason for that is the following:

> You can't access an  with different origin using JavaScript, it would be a huge security flaw if you could do it. For the same-origin policy browsers block scripts trying to access a frame with a different origin. [See more detailed answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/11974819)

Therefore when I tried to use puppeteer's methods:`Page.frames()` and `Page.mainFrame().` `ElementHandle.contentFrame()` I did not return any iframe to me. The problem is that it was happening silently and I couldn't figure out why it couldn't find anything.

Adding these arguments to launch options solved the issue:

 `'--disable-web-security',
'--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process'`

Comment: many thanks for your answer, this fixed my issue. in case you know can you please share any disadvantages of enabling these flags?