# How to scrape <html>...</html> INSIDE another <html>...</html> with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

Alright, so the page I'm trying to scrape with node.js puppeteer is structured like this

```
    <html lang = "en">
    ....
       <html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
            <a href = "link I'm trying to go to">Go to link</a>
       </html>
    </html>
```

I tried to click by selector and XPath. Neither worked, and I triple checked that both were right. I feel like it has something to do with this embedded html, and I don't know how to handle it? Can anyone help?

Comment: Is that inside an `iframe`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: As @MarcosCasagrande was hinting, if the content you wish to scrape is inside of an iframe, you'll need to scrape the URL of the iframe, as the DOM elements of the iframe content are not accessible from the parent document.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Yes it is inside an iframe. Lemme try scraping the url of the iframe

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez Yep, it's inside an iframe. I'm gonna try scraping that url

Comment: @ssBarBee const link = page.$x(xpath); link[0].click() and page.click(selector);. Other comments have pointed out that I should try scraping the url of the iframe, so I'm gonna try that right now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56420104/1861016 Refer to this @JohnSmith might be useful. In future add the code to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Other comments pointed out that content inside an iframe are not accessible from the parent document. I checked the code again, and turns out it was actually structured like this:

```
<html lang = "en">
....
   <iframe src = "url">
       <html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
           <a href = "link I'm trying to go to">Go to link</a>
       </html>
   </iframe>
</html>
```

So all I had to do was page.goto(url), and then I could scrape as normal. Thanks everyone!