# Scraper with puppeteer to website iframe there is a #document that does not let me get the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, scrapy, puppeteer

There is a casino website

https://www.888casino.com/live-casino/?reason=0#filters=all-roulette

When I enter one of the tables, an IFRAME opens and inside the IFRAME there is a #document

The #document does not let me select the data inside the iframe and that is where the data I need is

```
let mesaRoulette = false; 
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        userDataDir: './userData',
        args: ['--start-maximized'],
        devtools: true,
    });
    const [ page ] = await browser.pages();
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0); 

    await page.goto('https://es.888casino.com/live-casino/?reason=0#filters=all-roulette');
    await page.waitForTimeout(10000);
    const mesas = await page.$$('#orbit-container > div > main > div > div > div > div > div.item-wrapper-box');
    for (const mesa of mesas) {
        const tituloSelector = await mesa.$('#orbit-container > div > main > div > div > div > div > div.item-wrapper-box > div > span');
        if (tituloSelector){
            const titulo = await mesa.$eval('#orbit-container > div > main > div > div > div > div > div.item-wrapper-box > div > span', el => el.innerText);
            console.log(titulo);
            if (titulo === 'Roulette'){
                // const img = await mesa.$('#orbit-container > div > main > div > div > div > div > div.item-wrapper-box > div > img');
                await mesa.click('#orbit-container > div > main > div > div > div > div > div.item-wrapper-box');
                mesaRoulette = true;
                break;
            }
        };
    }
```

[IMAGE #Document problem selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwIBA.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select elements within an iframe element in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420047/how-to-select-elements-within-an-iframe-element-in-puppeteer)