# waitForSelector always timeout

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am making a webscraper in javascript (node) using puppeteer. I want to retrive the text of en element.

The selector has been copy-paste from the chrome dev tools, when I launch puppeteer `headless:false` the site loads correct.

'waitForSelector()' gives always this error message:
`` UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: waiting for selector `#petrolTable_data > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded ``
this is my code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function scrape(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false})
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto('https://economie.fgov.be/nl/themas/energie/energieprijzen/maximumprijzen/officieel-tarief-van-de', 
        {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
    await page.click('#fedconsent > div.orejime-AppContainer > div > div > div > button')
    //await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' })
    //#petrolTable_data > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)
    await page.waitForSelector('#petrolTable_data > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)')
    let el = await page.$("#petrolTable_data > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)")
    console.log(el)
    let text = await el.getProperty('textContent')
    console.log(text)
    browser.close()
}

scrape()
```

Comment: What data are you trying to get? Do you realize the table is in an iframe, `src="https://petrolprices.economie.fgov.be/petrolprices?locale=nl"`?

Comment: I did, but didn't know this made a difference. Thank you for pointing out that is can be an adventage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you want is in an iframe, so you'd have to [locate the frame first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56420104/6243352), then dip into it and query its contents. If you open the element inspector, iframe contents become unnaturally selectable. Assuming that the console translates 1:1 with Puppeteer is a common gotcha.

But an easier approach is to simply navigate directly to the frame source. This is faster, less work and more reliable, assuming the source won't change.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const url =
    "https://petrolprices.economie.fgov.be/petrolprices/?locale=nl";
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", request => {
    request.url() === url ? request.continue() : request.abort();
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const data = await page.$$eval("tr", els =>
    els
      .slice(1)
      .map(e =>
        [...e.querySelectorAll("td")]
          .slice(0, 2)
          .map(e => e.textContent),
      ),
  );
  console.table(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Output:

```
┌─────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ (index) │                      0                       │        1         │
├─────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│    0    │             'Benzine 95 RON E10'             │ '1,9310  euro/l' │
│    1    │             'Benzine 98 RON E5'              │ '2,1670  euro/l' │
│    2    │                 'Diesel B7'                  │ '2,0790  euro/l' │
│    3    │ 'Gasolie verwarming 50S (minder dan 2000 l)' │ '1,2923  euro/l' │
│    4    │   'Gasolie verwarming 50S (vanaf 2000 l)'    │ '1,2605  euro/l' │
└─────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Since the data is statically available, even easier and faster is to skip Puppeteer completely and use fetch/cheerio:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url =
  "https://petrolprices.economie.fgov.be/petrolprices/?locale=nl";
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const rows = [...$("table tr:has(td)")].map(e =>
      [...$(e).find("td:not(:last-child)")].map(e =>
        $(e).text().trim(),
      ),
    );
    console.table(rows);
  });
```

On my slow netbook with both scripts in the cache, Cheerio takes 2 seconds versus 6 seconds for Puppeteer.

If you don't have Node 18, install `node-fetch` or use Axios.

Generally speaking, I'm not a fan of browser-generated selectors because they're extremely sensitive; if one element changes unexpectedly in the chain, everything breaks. There are almost always more robust selectors you can choose. There are a few other antipatterns in your code, so I'll defer to [a blog post of mine](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns) for elaboration if you're curious.